# What is the formal specification of event sourcing (ES)?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

There are a lot of resources out there that address a couple aspects of ES, but most of them are pros/cons list or example snippets. Terms, such as `projection`, `apply`, `replay` are also used (mostly) without explanations or in slightly different contexts.

The best sample implementation with corresponding documentation and extra resources is the [CQRS Journey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554200.aspx) from Microsoft, and one can learn from it a lot, but it is not authoritative.

The closest to an informal spec I could find is [Leif Battermann's concise summary](http://blog.leifbattermann.de/2017/04/21/12-things-you-should-know-about-event-sourcing/), but his entire site has been down for a couple weeks now.

It may be that such comprehensive guideline does not exist, because it is a concept that became popular, people picked it up, started using it as they saw fit and no one will ever agree on the details anymore.

---

UPDATE (2/16/2018 11:03)

I missed Greg Young's (who coined the term CQRS) [Event Centric: Finding Simplicity in Complex Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321768221) book somehow. Would this be a publication to ES as Eric Evans' book is to Domain-Driven Design?

Comment: Hey @toraritte, have you found the answer you were looking for? I am also looking for a formal specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing to what you are looking for is probably [Martin Fowler's 2005 essay](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html);  Martin's description predates Young's introduction of DDDD/CQRS by a few years.

> Would this be a publication to ES as Eric Evans' book is to Domain-Driven Design?

No; among other things, Evans actually wrote the blue book.  *Event Centric* has not been written (as of October 2017).

Comment: I assumed this to be the case, but at least now it's explicit. Thanks.